# Capture debug log via subscriber access

Tags: apex, managed-package, subscriber, debug-logs

I am getting an exception from managed package code and I need to capture debug logs via Subscriber access so that all details from managed package code are displayed.

How can I enable this setting to access logs from managed package code

Answer (score 1):

Managed package debug logs can be enabled for orgs owned by package provider. However, not for subscriber orgs unless it is permitted by partner/customer.

Support can enable it if the package developer is the owner of the org or consent from package provider(owner) to enable logs.